# How can I make a shell alias work immediately?

Tags: bash, alias

Defining and using an alias in the same line does not seem to work:

```
$ alias x=ls; x
x: command not found
```

How can I "escape" `x` in the second call so that it is recognized as an alias?

Comment: Add the alias in the `.bashrc` file then simply write `source ~/.bashrc` now alias is permanent

Comment: I’ve tried && and I’ve tried putting multiple aliases on one line (which all get assigned) … but no matter how many you put on the line, it won’t execute the first (or any) in the same line - it’s very interesting!

Comment: See [Run alias after creation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389974)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't (in the usual ways). See [the Bash manual's section on Aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) (emphasis mine):

> The rules concerning the definition and use of aliases are somewhat
> confusing. Bash always reads at least one complete line of input, and
> all lines that make up a compound command, before executing any of the
> commands on that line or the compound command. Aliases are expanded
> when a command is read, not when it is executed. Therefore, an alias
> definition appearing on the same line as another command does not take
> effect until the next line of input is read. The commands following
> the alias definition on that line are not affected by the new alias.
> [...] **To be safe, always put alias definitions on a separate line, and
> do not use alias in compound commands.**

You can work around it by forcing a re-parsing using `eval`:

```
$ alias x=date; eval x
Fri Nov 12 18:20:54 JST 2021
```

Comment: `eval` is what I had been looking for! (I had tried `exec`, but `eval` hadn't crossed my mind before.) Thanks!

Comment: +1 `shopt -s extglob; eval echo '!(file)'`